# Subselect with count

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an sql query, which I want to write in `sequelize` code. It is a select, nested with a select count. Can anyone help me archiving this?

I want this raw query to work with `sequelize` in `nodejs`, but I dont want to use raw queries.

At the end there should be something like:

```
{product: [included product model], stock count: 5}

SELECT 
  products.id as 'ID', 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   from stocks 
   WHERE stocks.fk_product = products.id 
     AND stocks.sold = 0) AS 'counts' 
FROM products
```

I really dont know how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, s.fk_product as `ID` from stocks as s WHERE s.sold = 0 group by s.fk_product
```

Comment: I need this as sequelize query

Comment: You mean with CURSOR function?

Comment: Sorry man, I can't help you with nodejs, I know how to work with MySQL and java :)

Comment: You can do that using `HAVING 1 < 5` if you'll use my query.

Comment: ok, may be, postgres understood this syntax. Try with name or us main query as subquery for: `select * from (...) tmp where tmp.count < 5`